# How to edit registry value when I dont know full name of a field?

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

[image: here]

On the screenshot is what I am dealing with basically I know don't know the second part of the name before my game launches because its generated randomly based on monitor ID or something.

1. I would like to check if the key exist by partial name
2. Get full name if its found
3. Set my value for it

Currently I use this and its simply not possible to do it this way I think.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\AAA\MyApp\test\", false);

if (key != null)
{
    return (string)key.GetValue("Screenmanager Resolution ....");
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

I would then like to set the value myself like

```
key.SetValue("Screenmanager Resolution Width_h182942802", 1024, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Comment: So loop through all of the values and find the one you want?

Comment: How? Today I try this for first time.. I know only how to read or write fields with exact values. How to select all fields and get their names?

Comment: Something like ? for (int x = 0; x < (int)key.Length; x++)
                        {
                            key.Name.Contains("Screenmanager Resolution Width");
                        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value names with [`GetValueNames()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluenames(v=vs.110).aspx) and then see if the "Screen Resolution *" value exists:

```
string[] valueNames = key.GetValueNames();
string valueName = valueNames.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("Screenmanager Resolution Width_"));
if(valueName != null)
{
    return key.GetValue(valueName);
}
```

or without LINQ:

```
foreach(string valueName in key.GetValueNames())
{
    if(valueName.StartsWith("Screenmanager Resolution Width_"))
        return key.GetValue(valueName);
}
return null;
```

Comment: Thank you I tried 2 hours without LINQ but I think it reads always the last key. So it returned null or Screenmanager Resolution Width_ But with the LiNQ i got it working without problems